# Part of url including and following a hash symbol ignored in some instances

Tags: email, url, browser, hyperlink, url-fragment

My single page application (written in Elm) sends emails to people wishing to register with a hyperlink to the registration page.  The url has the following format: http://www.*domain_name*/*directory*/*page*#register/*user_email*/*jwt*

On a few occasions, users complain that they are taken back to the welcome page which is what would happen if the hash symbol and everything after it were ignored.

Are there browsers, or browser versions that would do this to a url, or are there email apps that can't handle hyperlinks with this type of url?

I accept that the jwt makes it quite a long url, but I would expect a different error if this were the problem.